# Autosuggestbox textchanged event is not firing

Tags: uwp, textchanged

I have this Autosuggestbox:

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="TxtOperator" x:FieldModifier="public" 
TxtOperator_TextChanged"/>
```

When i test this control on a tablet, the event textchanged is not firing but when i test this control on my desktop the even textchanged is firing.

C# code:

```
private void TxtOperator_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, 
AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{ 
      // Code     
}
```

Comment: I have some questions to ask you. 1) What's the OS build version on your tablet? What's the target/min platform version of your project?

Comment: 1) The build version on tablet is 10.0.15063. 2) Target/min platform version is the same, 10.0.15063. I tried change min platform version to 10.0 15086 but i had the same result; textchanged is not firing.